# problem I have 200 gb hard disk this will be a problem when downloading the blockchain geth ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

How much space does a PC need to download the complete portfolio of geth-ethereum on my pc? I have 200 gb of hard drive.

Comment: The current main Net data weight is a bit over 100 GB. So your 200GB would be very enough.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what *type* of sync you are trying to perform.

A *fast*  node sync will be well under 200GB and you will have no problems.

An *archival* node is approximately 1.5TB, which will not work. Depending on your application, it is likely that you will not need this.

Check out [this](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a) article for more information.